# Normal form for numbers defined by radicals?

Tags: algorithm, math, algebra

I'm writing a small computer algebra system that allows basic arithmetic operations and radicals. So the expressions are binary trees where inner nodes are operators `+ - * / ^` and leaves are rational numbers. Now I want, like other CAS do, simplify expressions, so for example it is

```
(5+sqrt(2)+sqrt(8)) / (1+sqrt(2)) = 1 + sqrt(8)
```

If you start with the left hand side, it is not obvious that you can rewrite it into the RHS. So how do other CAS do it? Is there a normal form of those expression, such that every expression can uniquely be written in a normal form? And is there a deterministic algorithm, that rewrites any expression into the normal form?

Comment: My immediate thought is that they do some sort of tree operations to rewrite it.  It's hardly obvious what to do though--I solve the above by using the conjugate, which is hardly obvious and (temporarily) complicates things.  Maybe a better fit for math.stackexchange?

Comment: See Landau's algorithm: http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/focs/1989/1982/00/063496.pdf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how CAS are made, but I think that the simplification procedure could be done through state-space search. You can have a set of rules how to transcribe one expression into another equivalent. Applications of these rules are edges in the search graph, and nodes are the expression trees. You can then search this graph to find a smallest possible tree (or small enough, or maybe one where no rule cannot be further applied).

An easier task might be a differentiation procedure, which is really only applying rules without (almost) the need to actually do any search. It can be very easilly written in prolog (athough I never did it, only our teacher of prolog at university told us).